# Password salting in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, password-protection

I have a project to start salting passwords. In order to avoid breaking our existing applications, this will require performing the hash inside a stored procedure.

Since I'm a total newbie on this topic, can you tell me where to get started.

Answer (score 1):

This would require a CLR function to do the hashing. Here is some info in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(VS.80).aspx). And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx) is a link for the hashing.